# How do I asynchronously add my javascript SDK in html and call initialize method once ready?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-analytics, sdk

How do i asynchronously load my sdk(JS file) in html and call the methods in it once my SDK object is ready on similar lines like how googles analytic code spinet does or facebook sdk , i have a public object MYSDK and it has some properties and method which i would like to invoke when script is loaded in the html.

Right now im doing something like this

```
(function (url,callback){
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.async = true;
    s.src = 'http://localhost:8181/init.js';
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
    s.onload=function(){
        mysdk.init({'userid':'37241d4f-fbd1-48ef-91fd-b359d20c7e31'});
    };
})();
```

I want to implement something like this .

```
(function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
 i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
 i[r] = i[r] || function () {
     (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
 }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
 a = s.createElement(o),
 m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
 a.async = 1;
 a.src = g;
 m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
 })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com
 analytics.js', 'ga');
 ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x', 'xxxxxx.com');
 ga('send', 'pageview');
```

What i tried .

```
  (function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m){
   i['my_sdkObjectName'] = r;
   i[r] = i[r] || function(){
   (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
   },
   i[r].l =1 * new Date();
   a = s.createElement(o),
   m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
   a.async = 1;
   a.src = g;
   m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)  
   })(window, document, 'script', 'http://localhost:8181/myt-sdk.js', 'my_sdk');
   my_sdk('init', '{"userid":"abcd-1234"}');
```

what i get ?
my_sdk is not a function.

console.log my_sdk gives

```
(){
(i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**ga** is defined inside google js file ([www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js](http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js))

You have to define **mysdk** inside your js file.

Comment: With your code mysdk is an object nkt a function.  You have to define function mysdk()  that get two parmeters

Comment: hey @Ygalbel i'm bit confused how do i implement that , Please check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/srp5x375/2/) what am i doing wrong .

Comment: I changed the fiddle. Check this version: https://jsfiddle.net/srp5x375/3/. The trick is to create `mySdk = function(){}`

Comment: so how would i call this   myObject('a', 'b'); once my script is added or ready?

Comment: You can. Because you define this function in external script

Comment: I get  following Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'a' of undefined,
this how im adding in my html
 (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {i['MyObject'] = r;i[r] = i[r] || function () {(i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)}, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
            a = s.createElement(o),m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
            a.async = 1;a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)    })(window, document, 'script', 'http://localhost/js/test-sdk.js', 'mob');mob('a', 'b'); console.log(mob.params['a'])

Comment: I checked it again. Google did complex work. you can set and get data only with ga('dasd,'dadsad') patterns. You can't call function directly. What happens it's it create a 'q' element in your object. and send them all calls until your script will be ready.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind time and help .I'm still failing to  implement ,is their any other simple example other then GA which may help me understand the conceptual way to implement .